# Akka.NET can C# actors be created within F# system?

Tags: c#, f#, akka.net

I'm trying to use some `ReceiveActor`s defined in a C# library within an F# system.  I tried creating the non-F# API `ActorSystem` but the call to `system.ActorOf(Props.Create(fun () -> new CSharpActor()))` doesn't work saying the function argument is not compatible.

I also couldn't find any documentation in the F# API pages on how to create actors defined in a C# library.  Is this just not done?  Is it generally a "bad" design - i.e. should the actor system be created within the library itself?

**EDIT**: Code that I am playing with below

*C# code*

```
namespace CsActors {
  using Akka.Actor;
  using System;

  public class CsActor : ReceiveActor {
    public CsActor() {
      Receive<string>(msg => { Console.WriteLine($"C# actor received: {msg}"); });
    }
  }

  public class CsActorWithArgs : ReceiveActor {
    public CsActorWithArgs(string prefix) {
      Receive<string>(msg => { Console.WriteLine($"{prefix}: {msg}"); });
    }
  }
}
```

*F# script*

```
#I @"../build"

#r @"Akka.dll"
#r @"Akka.FSharp.dll"
#r @"CsActors.dll"

open Akka.Actor
open Akka.FSharp
open CsActors

let system = System.create "fcmixed" (Configuration.load())

// fails at runtime with "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression'."
//let c1 = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(fun _ -> CsActor()))

// works if CsActor has constructor with no arguments
let c2 = system.ActorOf<CsActor> "c2"
c2 <! "foo"

// if actor doesn't have default constructor - this won't compile
//let c3 = system.ActorOf<CsActorWithArgs> "c3"

// Horusiath solution works for actors requiring arguments
let c4 = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(typeof<CsActorWithArgs>, [| box "c4-prefix" |]))
c4 <! "foo"


// Just for fun trying to use suggestion by dumetrulo (couldn't quite get it to work...)
// copied Lambda module from http://www.fssnip.net/ts/title/F-lambda-to-C-LINQ-Expression
//module Lambda =
//    open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
//    open System.Linq.Expressions
//    let toExpression (``f# lambda`` : Quotations.Expr<'a>) =
//        ``f# lambda``
//        |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression
//        |> unbox<Expression<'a>>
//let c5 = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(<@ (fun _ -> CsActorWithArgs "c5-prefix") @> |> Lambda.toExpression))
//c5 <! "foo"
```

Comment: C# and F# both compile down to IL. It should be no different than calling any other F# library, so long as you provide the right types and arguments etc everything should work.

Comment: can you post the type signature, as well as the exact error message.

Comment: You probably need to cast that function to the appropriate delegate type for C#

Comment: According to the Akka.net source (https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Actor/Props.cs line 389), Props.Create() takes a LINQ Expression<_> as its argument, and it seems that converting an F# lambda to an Expression<_> requires some additional steps you can easily find on the web.

Comment: It should work as written in the question; I tried just that (same constellation - actors defined in a C# project and used from F#) and did not get any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Props.Create` with function won't work, because what `Props.Create(() => new Actor(a, b))` in C# does is actually taking an expression, and deconstructing it into actor type and constructor arguments. This is necessary, because one of the Props requirements is that it has to be serializable.

What you can do is to use another overload of `Props.Create(typeof<MyActor>, [| box myArg1; box myArg2 |])` which essentially does the same, just without compile type safety.

That being said, it'd be better if you'd just use [Akkling](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling/) or [Akka.FSharp](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/tree/dev/src/core/Akka.FSharp) API when possible.